# Logging and Configuration Systems: Circular Dependency

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

Assume a typical scenario where the initial settings of an application are loaded at startup from a configuration file. The application also has a logger. The parameters of the logger (e.g. verbosity level, log file path, etc.) are ideally also stored in the configuration file. However, it is also desirable that the configuration loader log information about parameter loading, for example

> Attempting to load parameter LogVerbosity. Parameter is absent. Using the default value: 4.

Thus, we see a circular dependency between the two components. The configuration loader needs a ready-to-use logger, and a logger needs configuration parameters to initialize itself. This seems to me to be a problem typical enough to have canonical solutions to it, but I was unable to find anything.

Of course, one can roll some ad-hoc solutions but I'm interested in the best industry practices.

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the canonical solution is: don't mix logging and configuration!

Imagine that there is a bug triggered by the configuration file parsing (but you don't know that yet!). You change the configuration file to enable logging. Now the parsing doesn't trigger the bug, and everything looks right, until you disable logging again...

So: more generically, and by principle, one wants to minimize the disruption that the debugging infrastructure (including logging) introduces to a program; in the ideal case, debugging functionality would be orthogonal to anything that the application does, to avoid *causing* [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Mixing normal configuration with logging configuration is already against this principle.

But also empirically, you can see how the well-known logging libraries work: they all have their own configuration files, independent of any configuration going on in the application, so you can change the logging behaviour without ever messing with the application itself. So you can repeat a problematic run of an application, only changing its logging behaviour and hopefully nothing else. That's how Log4j and its family of ports, or the already mentioned nlog, work.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to log parameters in order to be able to investigate them later on, for example in the case of a bug. What is obvious, it's possible only if they'll be persisted in a file or another storage. It implies that a logger **must** be properly configured in order to do so. So the basic question is:

*Can we assume that a logger will be able to log at least startup parameters?*

**Yes**

This case is trivial. I'd simply:

1. Read configuration parameters of a logger.
2. Initialize a logger.
3. Log parameters of a logger.
4. Read other parameters.
5. Log other parameters.

**No**

This case is more complex. I think that a good solution is to use a default, hard-coded set of parameters for a logger. It will guarantee that it'll be possible to safely log startup parameters:

1. Initialize a logger with default (hard-coded) parameters.
2. Read configuration parameters.
3. Log parameters.
4. Initialize a logger based on the parameters from the configuration file.
5. Try to log parameters once again.

If a configuration of a logger is correct you'll be able to find all parameters in a standard log location. If a configuration is wrong, you still will be able to find them but in the default (hard-coded) location.

Alternatively, instead of using a logger in the step 1, you can simply write startup parameters to a file (in a working directory of an application) using standard mechanisms like `fstream`...

**Additional comments**

Some logging libraries like *nlog* can be configured (*throwExceptions = true*) to raise errors in the case of a wrong configuration. Unhandled exceptions should be then logged by an operating system.

If you use a logging library of this kind you can turn this option on and use a solution 1 above. If application started then you'll find startup parameters in a log. If it didn't started, you should examine a system log.

Comment: The logger must be correctly configured, yes; but that has no connection to the rest. Particularly, you don't even need a filesystem for either the logging configuration or for the logging itself. Configuration could be done programatically, as is the case with the already mentioned nlog. And logging can be done in-memory, as is done with klog in Linux, and later be accessed in a variety of ways.

Comment: @hmijail - The question was about a problem of logging startup parameters including configuration of a logger. And I think that my answer addressed this problem. There might be a better solution and I'll be happy to hear it. However, your answer doesn't provide it, so I don't understand why you downvoted. Logging to a file system is only an example, it can be anything else for example a database, a system log...

Comment: @MichałKomorowski, the question explicitly asks for "canonical solutions" and "best industry practices" vs "ad-hoc solutions". Your answer gives 2 ad-hoc solutions, without addressing at all whether this is a good idea, much less anything that could be called "canonical". If you want to compare, my answer covers both the theory of what would be best, and examples of how well-known players in the industry do exactly that. But of course if you don't like it, feel free to down-vote it.

Comment: (I should clarify: the point of my first comment was that you were, IMO, paying too much attention to specifics, and none to the overarching question. I see now that it was not clear, sorry about that)